# How to represent this data with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, networking, d3.js, hierarchical-data

I will try to make a resume of my problem and give some additional information if someone have a lead for me.
I want to display the history of an element in an application. How it have been construct and what it have done. So it could have 1+ parents, 1+ brothers and 1+ children. It's like a genealogy tree but it could have 3 parents and parents and children can be mixed to give others children. So I thought about a network, and I ended with this : 
[http://jsfiddle.net/ggrwc8p6/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/ggrwc8p6/2/)

```
var data = {
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"1-STS","group":1},
    {"name":"2-STS","group":1},
      {"name":"1-ADN","group":2},
      {"name":"2-ADN","group":2},
    {"name":"3-ADN","group":2},
    {"name":"4-ADN","group":2}
  ],
  "links":[
      {"source":0,"target":2,"value":1},
      {"source":1,"target":2,"value":1},
      {"source":2,"target":3,"value":5},
      {"source":3,"target":4,"value":5},
      {"source":3,"target":5,"value":5}
  ]
};

var width = 500,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(120)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

function makeIt(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.group; })
      .attr("r", 15)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
}
makeIt("",data);
```

My problem here are :

- How can I make this like a tree ? From top to bottom and not with no hierarchy like here ?
- How can I put some text in dot (title) and lines ?

Thank for the people that will help me.
++

Comment: Would a Sankey layout work? Branches there can diverge and re-merge: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/sankey-diagrams-description-of-d3js-code.html

Comment: @Maggie Hi ! I didn't know about this type of layout. I look at it and I think it's not my case. Because I need like a family tree : a hierarchie...